# Multiple Windows on Startup Items - How to Remove

Tags: bootcamp, windows, unix, startup

I currently have 2 SSDs on my Macbook Pro 2010 13", on which I have successfully installed MacOS & Ubuntu on 1 SSD, and Windows on the other. All is working fine and successfully installed. The issue now only, after I installed Ubuntu, I have multiple Windows drives showing up which created double options. One of these drives are totally useless. How do I remove this so it's back to the original 3 options as it should be? (The first Windows icon from the left is the useless one). 
Thanks in advance for anyone that willing to help or advise.

[image: Image on startup manager]
[image: Image of contents of the EFI folder on disk1s1]

Below my diskutil list

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:               Windows_NTFS BOOTCAMP                250.1 GB   disk0s1

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         151.8 GB   disk1s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data                         7.9 GB     disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data                         79.9 GB    disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +151.8 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume dn1122                  13.9 GB    disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 24.5 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                512.1 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk2s4
```

```
***sudo fdisk /dev/disk1
Disk: /dev/disk1    geometry: 29185/255/63 [468862128 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   1 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
*2: DA 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  296551216] <Unknown ID>
 3: 82 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 296962048 -   15362048] Linux swap  
 4: 83 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 312586240 -  156012544] Linux files*
```

Comment: I suppect there are Windows boot files in `disk1s1`. Can you show the contents of the `EFI` folder in the root folder of the FAT32 volume stored in this partition? The other possibility is `disk1` is hybrid partitioned. Any possibility you could post the output form `sudo fdisk /dev/disk1`? You may need to disable SIP or boot to recovery before entering this command.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Updated contents of EFI folder on disk1s1 and fdisk output sir.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Sir, in this case, that my windows on the other SSD which is disk0. I could not find any EFI partition to change it to windows logo, right?

Comment: You have a BIOS booting Windows. This is the correct installation of Windows for your model/year Mac. I suppose the Windows logo icon should go in the Windows partition. However, doing so should **not** work, because the firmware cannot read NTFS formatted volumes. So there probably is no way to change the icon displayed in the Startup Manager when you have a BIOS booting Windows.

Comment: @DavidAnderson noted sir! I will just go with the current situation. Thank you and bless you and your family as always sir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Remove Windows from Startup Manager

You at least need to remove the hybrid partitioning on `disk1`. I assuming this drive would be `/dev/sda` under Ubuntu. If not, then make the appropriate substitution. The command below can be entered in a Ubuntu terminal window to list the drives and partitions.

```
sudo lsblk -e7
```

You can use [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) included with Ubuntu to remove the hybrid partitioning. This is a interactive command. The command and user input is given below.

```
sudo gdisk /dev/sda
x
n
w
y
```

### How to change `EFI Boot` to `Ubuntu` (Optional)

I noticed you have a icon for Ubuntu, but are still using the default label.

Enter the following commands in a macOS Terminal application window.

```
sudo diskutil mount disk1s1
sudo bless --folder /Volumes/EFI/EFI/Boot --label Ubuntu
diskutil unmount disk1s1
```

### How to Restore Hybrid Partitioning to the Windows Drive.

I assuming this drive would be `/dev/disk0` under macOS. If not, then make the appropriate substitution. The command below can be entered in a Terminal application window to list the drives and partitions.

```
diskutil list
```

You can use [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) installed in macOS to partially convert `disk0` from a GPT to MBR partition table. This is a interactive command. The command and user input is given below.

```
sudo gdisk /dev/disk0
r
h
1
n
07
y
n
w
y
```

Next, use the following commands to finish the conversion.

```
sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk0
s 2
0
q
y
diskutil unmountdisk disk0
gpt destroy /dev/disk0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help sir! It works now only 3 options on boot now. Next question, I changed that ubuntu logo and now the label from your direction.

I wonder if I can change the windows and MacOs Logo as well? If can how sir?

Comment: I guess I will follow your answer of someone's question here https://bit.ly/2ytveKS

Comment: Sir, I sid something wrong. I used /dev/sdb to remove the hybrid partition which now I realised that I need to remove hybrid from /dev/sda. I tried to reactivate hybrid using gdisk from MacOs and now the windows goes to that BSOD showing the winload.exe failed. I tried recovery using the usb from previous windows installation but doesn’t seems to fix startup repair. In case you have advice I’m open 

Comment: I added the commands to undo the steps you applied to `disk0` by mistake. If you want me to verify the commands are correct, then first post the output of `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` and `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`. These two commands will not change `disk0`.

Comment: Sir, I've been trying here and there to fix the current windows on that single SSD. What I found now is the volume on that SSD for the BOOTCAMP now is hidden. And "diskpart" is unable to change attribute to "unhide" the dynamic drive. I am planning to format my SSD and re-do the windows installation to the SSD with the same MacOS. And when all finish, clone the WindowsOS to the other SSD.

Do you think this current windows still able to save sir? Or less possibility?

Comment: To answer your questions, you would have to post the output from `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` and `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0`. These two commands will not change `disk0`. You can post the output to your question.

Comment: Sir, first of all thank you very much for the help. I got it sorted by format and reinstall again from the start :( painful but got the job done. Appreciate your help sir!